# about Visual formatting model

Tags: css, language-lawyer

I'm reading the CSS specifications, but I'm facing some issues that are causing confusion. I hope fellow users can help clarify them.

1. Will BFC affect grandchildren elements?
2. If a div is not a BFC, what type of FC is it, and how are its internal elements laid out?
3. The body element is not a BFC container, so why do its internal elements still experience margin collapsing and vertical arrangement? Aren't these features exclusive to BFC?
4. The CSS specification states that boxes within a Block Formatting Context (BFC) will be arranged vertically one by one. However, does this apply to inline-level elements within a BFC as well? If not, does this mean the CSS specification is not precise enough in its description?

```html
<style>
  .wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>你好</span>
  <div>世界</div>
  <span>哈哈</span>
    <span>呵呵</span>
</div>
```

Will this code generate an anonymous box? If so, how will it be generated specifically?

Could you help me clarify something?

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Will BFC affect grandchildren elements?

It probably depends on what you mean by "affect". Assuming the intermediate child object does not establish an Independent Formatting Context, then the grandchild will participate in, i.e. be laid out in accordance with, the BFC.

> 2. If a div is not a BFC, what type of FC is it, and how are its internal elements laid out?

It could establish a different formatting context, or it could establish no formatting context at all.

> 3. The body element is not a BFC container, so why do its internal elements still experience margin collapsing and vertical arrangement? Aren't these features exclusive to BFC?

Because the whether internal elements do those things or not depends on whether they participate in *any* ancestor BFC. They will always be participating in some Independent Formatting Context established by an ancestor, which may or may not be a BFC.

> 4. The CSS specification states that boxes within a Block Formatting Context (BFC) will be arranged vertically one by one. However, does this apply to inline-level elements within a BFC as well? If not, does this mean the CSS specification is not precise enough in its description?

Inline-level elements participate in an Inline Formatting Context, not a BFC. CSS2 could be more precise about this, yes.

> Will this code generate an anonymous box?

There will be one anonymous block box around the first span, and one around the other two spans.